# What are the strongest boosting alternatives to Adaboost?

Tags: boosting, ensemble-learning

Whenever boosting is brought up, Adaboost is the first algorithm to be listed.  What are the most popular boosting algorithms that *aren't* Adaboost?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is a nice summery about "ensemble based systems": boosting & classifier  fusion  etc'

Some of the more common alternatives are described & discussed in more details:

http://users.rowan.edu/~polikar/RESEARCH/PUBLICATIONS/csm06.pdf